# Laravel 4: Load External View

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm moving from CodeIgniter to Laravel 4 and I haven't been able to find a decent way to load a view from an external application. My setup will be 10-15 apps with their own Laravel installation. These apps are all unique apps. However, they all use to the same template and I don't want to have 10-15 copies of the same file throughout all my apps. So, I'm trying to figure out a way to share this template among all these apps. I did this in CodeIgniter by loading an external view and providing the path to centralized location that contained the template file. What is the best practice in Laravel to make this happen?

Edit: I'm not sure if I did a good job explaining what I'm trying to do. Basically, I have a blade layout file that I want to use as a template for all of my apps. I'm trying to avoid having to copy and paste this file into every installation. All of these installations will be on the same server so I want a centralized location where I could store this blade layout file and use it for each app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel you can set many paths to your views in `app/conf/views.php`:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| View Storage Paths
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Most templating systems load templates from disk. Here you may specify
| an array of paths that should be checked for your views. Of course
| the usual Laravel view path has already been registered for you.
|
*/

'paths' => array(__DIR__.'/../views'),
```

You can just add your external path there and Laravel will also try to find your views in this new path.

You can even do something like this:

```
'paths' => array(__DIR__.'/../views', '/var/www/'),
```

And in your application use it as

```
return View::make('myotherapp/views/users/show');
```

And Laravel will find the file

```
/var/www/myotherapp/views/users/show.php
```

For you.

Comment: Hi @antonio, I was wandering if there was a way to include a layout from an external package like this too. I'm currently intending to split up a site via subdomain and load in the consistent layout styling from an external composer package.